# Unexpected senseless optimization tries of a simple for loop (in Visual C++ 2017)

Tags: c++, loops, assembly, visual-c++, optimization

I was playing around with the Visual C++ 2017 compiler doing some tests on how to implement various things to get maximum performance from the code when I encountered a behaviour I did not expect nor can I explain it.

I created a simple foreach method to process all values in my container. The container itself only stores a `size_t size` and an `int *ptr`.

This is the code of the foreach method taking a Lambda in f:

```
template<class F>
__declspec(noinline) void foreach(F f)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        f(ptr[i]);
}
```

I call it with

```
int sum = 0;
v.foreach([&](int item) { sum += item; });
```

When it is compiled a part of the binary looks like this:

```
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF6B3382310  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF6B3382312  mov         qword ptr [f],rdx  
00007FF6B3382317  cmp         qword ptr [rcx],rax  
00007FF6B338231A  jbe         MyVector::foreach<<lambda_c1957c9a484ac2f96c41b63c392e4950> >+2Ah (07FF6B338233Ah)  
00007FF6B338231C  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
            f(ptr[i]);
00007FF6B3382320  mov         r8,qword ptr [rcx+8]  
00007FF6B3382324  mov         r9d,dword ptr [r8+rax*4]  
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF6B3382328  inc         rax  
            f(ptr[i]);
00007FF6B338232B  add         dword ptr [rdx],r9d  
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF6B338232E  cmp         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF6B3382331  jae         MyVector::foreach<<lambda_c1957c9a484ac2f96c41b63c392e4950> >+2Ah (07FF6B338233Ah)  
00007FF6B3382333  mov         rdx,qword ptr [f]  
00007FF6B3382338  jmp         MyVector::foreach<<lambda_c1957c9a484ac2f96c41b63c392e4950> >+10h (07FF6B3382320h)  
    }
00007FF6B338233A  ret
```

Analysis:

- So `rcx` is the address of the `size` and also the address of `this` (as `size` is the first member of the object).
- `rdx` seens to be the address of the Lambda functor and it is also the address if the `sum` member of the Lambda.
- In address xxx320 the `ptr` is loaded into register r8.
- From xxx324 to xxx338 is the main loop. Value of ptr[i] is loaded into r9d, rax (the ptr) is incremented and r9d is added to the sum-member of the Lambda object.

The first 2 of my 3 questions are:

- Why is address xxx320 part of the loop? r8 is not changed and the ptr-member is not marked `volatile`. Shouldn't the jmp in xxx338 point to xxx324 instead?
- Why is the lambda address cached from `rdx` to `[f]` in xxx312 and restored to `rdx` in xxx333 in every loop? rdx is not changed, so why does the compiler reload it?

I tried to get rid of these 'inefficiencies' and found that the following source creates a more reasonable machine code:

```
template<class F>
__declspec(noinline) void foreach(F f)
{
    register auto f2 = f;
    register auto p = ptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        f2(p[i]);
}
```

The generated machine code is

```
    register auto f2 = f;
        register auto p = ptr;
00007FF7E79A2340  mov         r9,qword ptr [rcx+8]  

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF7E79A2344  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF7E79A2346  cmp         qword ptr [rcx],rax  
00007FF7E79A2349  jbe         MyCheckedVector::foreach<<lambda_27103c2606044b6f9a288cfb44283d2c> >+1Fh (07FF7E79A235Fh)  
00007FF7E79A234B  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
            f2(p[i]);
00007FF7E79A2350  mov         r8d,dword ptr [r9+rax*4]  

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF7E79A2354  inc         rax  
            f2(p[i]);
00007FF7E79A2357  add         dword ptr [rdx],r8d  

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
00007FF7E79A235A  cmp         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FF7E79A235D  jb          MyCheckedVector::foreach<<lambda_27103c2606044b6f9a288cfb44283d2c> >+10h (07FF7E79A2350h)  
    }
00007FF7E79A235F  ret
```

It fixes to problems of the original source:

- `ptr` or `r9` is only loaded at the beginning of the method.
- `rdx` (the lambda's address) is not cached and simply stored in the `rdx`register.
- the main loop only iterates from xxx350 tp xxx35D (Load ptr[i] into `r8d`, increment i in `rax`, add ptr[i] cached in `r8d` to Lambda member sum addressed with `rdx`, check if `rax` >= size in address at `rcx`

And my third question is:

How comes this piece if machine code actually runs at the same speed as the original version? It's only having 5 instructions per loop versus 8 instructions in the original loop and all 5 instructions are also present in the original loop.

Maybe I should also mention my optimization settings:

- Full Optimization
- Inline Function Expansion: Any Suitable
- Intrinsics: Yes
- Favor fast code
- Whole Program Optimization
- Enhanced Instruction Set: Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2)

I know I should leave optimizations to the compiler, but sometimes I dig into machine code out of curiosity. I would really appreciate any explanations!

**--- UPDATE ---**

I have created an example which is not 100% the original code but creates the same machine code. The example uses only 1K values (4000 Byte data) in the inner loop so memory access should not be limiting performance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

static const auto OuterLoops = 100000;

class MyContainer
{
    static const auto Items = 100000000 / OuterLoops;

public:
    MyContainer()
        : size(Items),
        ptr(new int[Items])
    {
        // Make sure memory is paged
        std::fill(ptr, ptr + size, 0xA5);
    }

    template<class F> __declspec(noinline) auto foreach1(F f)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            f(ptr[i]);
    }

    template<class F> __declspec(noinline) auto foreach2(F f)
    {
        const register auto sizer = size;
        const register auto fr = f;
        const register auto ptrr = ptr;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizer; ++i)
            fr(ptrr[i]);
    }

private:
    size_t size;
    int *ptr;
};

template<class F>
void measureSpeed(const char *const caption, F f)
{
    std::vector<int> results(11);

    for (auto& result : results)
    {
        for (auto a = clock(); a == clock(); );
        const auto start1 = clock();

        for(int i = 0; i < OuterLoops; ++i)
            f();

        result = clock() - start1;
    }

    std::sort(results.begin(), results.end());
    std::cout << caption << ": " << results[results.size() / 2] << " (";
    for (const auto& result : results)
        std::cout << result << ' ';
    std::cout << "\b)" << std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyContainer c;

    int s1 = 0;
    measureSpeed("foreach1", [&]() { c.foreach1([&](const auto v) { s1 += v; }); });

    int s2 = 0;
    measureSpeed("foreach2", [&]() { c.foreach2([&](const auto v) { s2 += v; }); });

    if (s1 != s2)
        std::cerr << "Comparing nonsense" << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The results I get are a bit variing, but foreach2 is always about 5% slower than foreach1:

```
foreach1: 195 (190 191 192 193 195 195 195 195 196 196 197)
foreach2: 207 (202 202 205 206 206 207 208 208 212 213 214)
```

(The first value is the median of all test runs followed by the sorted timings of all test runs. The values are from clock() and not converted, but at least with Visual Studio Platform Toolset v140 these are milliseconds.)

Comment: Maybe it's a given but you are compiling with optimizations enabled, i.e. in Release mode, right?

Comment: I think I am using maximum optimization. I've added my settings to the question.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `__restrict` qualifier to the array pointer just in case the optimizer is having trouble disproving aliasing against the lambda state? You'd think it wouldn't but then again it couldn't hurt.

Comment: In any event performance not increasing despite dropping instructions is generally a sign that the bottleneck lies elsewhere. In this case I would tend to suspect memory access if the array is large.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for the __restrict idea. I will try this tomorrow as i am already afk.

Comment: @Andreas H.: It is perhaps obvious since you have already done so for other variables but caching `size` in a local variable should help avoid the memory access in the innerloop and, perhaps more importantly, permit the compiler get fancy with unrolling and vectorization.

Comment: Does it *matter*? I mean, does it make any significant difference to any performance critical part of your code?  If not, then why are you obsessing about it?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: I interpret the question as an exercise to achieve a better understanding of the code generator rather than a specific critical innerloop requiring optimization. Periodically checking up on the optimizer to insure that you are not in the habit of inadvertently raised unexpected stumbling blocks should certainly be standard practice on any performance-sensitive projects.

Comment: It all started with the question why `for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) f (ptr [i])` is 10 to 20 percent faster than `for (auto p = ptr; p < endptr; ++p) f (*p)`.

Comment: @AndreasH. I will second the request to give a minimal and complete example, as a source file that can be compiled by itself and then its object code is checked. Currently we don't know what else can affect your case. It doesn't need to be compiled as runnable binary, but at least compiled alone.

Comment: I've added an (C++14) example to the question. Its not the original code (because it would not be minimal) but it generates the same machine code and same difference in speed.

Comment: Another strange thing is that for a source like `for (auto p = ptr; p != endptr; ++p) f(*p);` the compiler generates code to calculate the difference between endptr and ptr and uses a register for p and a second register for the count. Both registers are advanced in every iteration. And guess what: It's faster that the version using only one register for `ptr`. Maybe this is because the processor can process the pointer and the counter operations independently and the conditional jump can be calculated while the memory operation is still in progress?

Comment: @Andreas H.: It seems the bottleneck here is entirely the read-modify-write accumulation of the sum (the `add` to memory), forming a long dependency chain of high latency instructions. For reference I get a ~3.5x speedup with a local accumulator and 16x with SIMD. Anyway, permitting inlining allows VC2015 to drop the load while unfortunately still preserving the store despite `restrict`. This compiler version would appear to have trouble disentangling lambda state references and so they should perhaps be used with care in critical innerloops, unless I am missing an important optimizer option.

Comment: Iʼve checked your full example with GCC and Clang. Results: Clang4.0 with optlevel >= 1, GCC (5,6) with optlevel 3 - all times are 3. GCC with -O2: all times are 5. GCC with -O: 24 for cycle 1 and 25-26 for cycle 2. I suggest considering using Clang. VC is extremely specific in its logic and seems tending to lag behind, more and more.

Comment: It seems that the Visual C++ compiler really does no good job eliminating some operations (as it's always reloading the Lambdas address for example) but what I really do not understand (my third question): why is the resulting 'inefficient' 8-ops machine code at least as fast as the 'optimized' 5-ops version when all of the 5-ops are also present in the 8-ops inner loop?

Comment: @Andreas H.: Because those 5 instructions are _not_ on the critical path and can be executed in parallel. On my CPU (Skylake) the addition to memory has a latency of 5 which dominates the latencies of all other work, and clearly each iteration depends on the previous. Therefore it becomes the limiting factor which must be removed and you would see nearly identical performance even if everything else was removed.

Comment: @doynax: In your last comment you confirmed what I was beginning to suspect. So this answers my last question. Thank you for that. Perhaps you could compose and answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is address xxx320 part of the loop? r8 is not changed and the ptr-member is not marked volatile. Shouldn't the jmp in xxx338 point to xxx324 instead?
>
> Why is the lambda address cached from rdx to [f] in xxx312 and restored to rdx in xxx333 in every loop? rdx is not changed, so why does the compiler reload it?

r8 and rdx are both volatile registers, which don't survive a function call, so at some point the optimizer will be thinking that the call to f() will cause the values to be spilled.

When it does optimize away the actual function call, it probably does not check the code as a single instruction stream and remove the redundant reloads.

The performance has been driven by the add function, which means the extra unneeded operations, do not drive the performance of the code.